# How to convert date into a DateValue code (like in vba)?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a database with the following columns:`ID`, `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `COD_DATA`, and `VALUE`.

`COD_DATA` stores a value representing the conversion of `YEAR` and `MONTH` into a code, which was initially made in Excel VBA. For example, in Excel VBA `DateValue(01/05/2019)` returns `43586`.

Now I want to search certain parameters in the database and show the results in a gridview. One of the search values is a range of dates (e.g. search rows between dates xx/xx/xxxx and yy/yy/yyyy). Is there any way I can convert these two dates that will be inserted by the user into a code like DateValue function in vba?

Comment: The VBA docs https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252 explain the very simple logic behind the DateValue function (see the "Remarks" section specifically) ...I think you could re-implement it quite easily, if no-one has already done so.

Comment: Why do you want to do that at all? Why not use proper DateTime values in the application and `date` or `datetime2` values in the database? There's no point trying to copy legacy code into platforms that no longer need it. If you want to store just a date use `date`. If you want to get a date-only value from a DateTime, use `DateTime.Date`

Comment: Actually, it seems Microsoft may have already done so... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?view=netframework-4.8 . All I did was google "C#  DateValue VBA function".

Comment: But TBH it might be better to do a one-off conversion of the database values into a regular `datetime2` column and then write regular SQL and .NET code to deal with them (that's assuming you no longer need to interface with Excel)

Comment: @ADyson I'm pretty sure SQL Server can do the same conversion too. Using that OA Values in a modern application is a terrible idea.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree it's not ideal but it appears to be an option in .NET, that's all. OP can always convert the database data as we've both suggested and then work in a better way.

Comment: Excel doesn't have *any* problems with date types either, definitely not `date`. There's no reason to store dates as OADate values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand your point of view but if I search a range of dates, let's say between 01/09/2019 and  31/12/2019, how would it find anything since the database has only a column for month and another year separately as ```int's```?

Comment: @JohnnyAbreu the point of Panagiotis' suggestion and mine is to do away with that `COD_DATA` column by converting the data so you can move it to a standard `datetime2` data type, and then applying regular sorting/filtering etc using regular dates. I don't believe either of us suggested you should rely purely on your `YEAR` and `MONTH` columns. Indeed they are probably redundant anyway since the same information already exists in the other column.

Comment: @ADyson problem is I'm not allowed to change anything in the database at the moment

Comment: @JohnnyAbreu the same way you would for every number - use `BETWEEN` or `WHERE`. Dates aren't strings and have no format. They are binary values just like integers. If the database contains separate columns for year and month, a DateValue *won't* fix anything. It can't represent months, only full dates.

Comment: @JohnnyAbreu why not, might I ask? if you're updating the application then it's reasonable to update the database at the same time. Restricting that seems a bit arbitrary, unless there's an underlying reason. Is Excel still writing stuff into this table or something?

Comment: @ADyson yes, currently users are inserting the data into the database through the vba application in excel, which was developed previously by someone else. If I was the one in control I wouldn't have done it this way.

Comment: Could you consider updating the Excel app at the same time so it uses regular DateTime objects? That would be a neater solution overall.

Comment: @ADyson I found that "at the same time" can lead to ... situations. Maybe it's an option to make a "soft" transition: 1. Add column in DB, 2. Have VBA populate both, 3. Conversion run where new column is null, 4. Make App use new column, 5. Make VBA write new column only, 6. drop legacy column.

Comment: @Fildor yes that would be a sensible approach (although, good testing should significantly reduce the risk). Actually you could reduce the risk still further by replacing "Make VBA populate both" with "set a trigger which populates the new column from the old column", and "drop legacy column" with "drop legacy column and trigger". Then there's only one change needed to the VBA app :-)

Comment: No doubt it would. I'd suggest my superiors to update it but it would probably mess up many things in the process... I'm still trying to figure the whole process, because I'm relatively new here, but I think even one small change would probably result in a ton of changes in other procedures and I don't think they want to "waste" that much time in rewriting the whole system at this point.

Comment: If that's really the case (and you can't even convince them to use a softer, more gradual approach as Fildor mentions, to reduce the "step-change" problem), then you may be stuck with doing the conversions and incurring the associated potential performance (and even accuracy) penalties involved. If you can demonstrate that keeping the current approach is, in itself, a risk, and/or if they care that you are just piling on even more technical debt, then you might be able to get clearance to go with the better solution.